# Android - New language font

Tags: java, android

I need to support malayalam(South Indian language) font for my application.

I found a way of changing the typeface of a textView/edittext, but it is working only for default supported languages. For malayalam, it is showing square boxes. Is there a way to do that without rooting. Please refer myalpha multiling keyboard apps. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is not supporting malayalam, not even in the latest release Icecream Sandwhich. But hindi is supporting in ICS. Lets hope in future they will add malayalam also

Please refer

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.3.html

But if you root your phone you will be able add malayalam font to your android phone.

Comment: i have seen some app like myalpha and multiLing keyboard .. i wonder how they do that without rooting..

Comment: I think those application were done in Adobe flex. Not in android. Those flex applications will work in android phone which is having Adobe AIR support. For example malayala manorama tv android app. Flex will support all Unicode languages including malayalam

Comment: if we root the phone and install the malayalam font.. do you have any idea about copy paste functionality working?  just rooting will not be enough for a proper rendering of fonts (including copy|paste)..

Comment: from jelly bean malayalam is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps I hope it will work for you.

1. Copy ttf file of malayalam in your assets folder of android project.
2. Now use following code snippet.

   edittext.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "malayalam.ttf"));

Try this if it works for you then please let me know.